# Solr returning unmatched documents

Tags: lucene, solr5

I am writing query get all documents which has "am" or "pm" in their name, and my query goes like this: **(sellerName:am pm)**.

Returned document as follows:

**doc1:**

```
  seller name:am
  city: bangalore 
  state:Kar
  country:In
  zip:560034
```

**doc2:**

```
          seller name:pm
          city: bang
          state:Kar
          country:In
          zip:560034
```

**doc3:**

```
      seller name: Ganesh
      city: bang
      state:Kar pm
      country:In
      zip:560034
```

First two documents are getting returned as we have **am** or **pm** in their name, 
My question is even though we don't have am or pm in the seller name of **Doc3** still this is even getting as match.
This is because we have **pm** in **zip** code if doc3.

I don't want this to be returned as a result. How can I do this? And why its matching with the Doc3, even though doc3 does not contain am or pm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard lucene query syntax.

`sellerName:am pm` translates to `sellerName:am defaultField:pm`.  You're default field is probably an ["all" field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields), or something like that, I would guess.

Your query should be:  `sellerName:(am pm)`

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to determine what query is being sent to Lucene is by sending debugQuery=true which tells you exactly how the query is parsed.